# Loop with nested polymer elements?

Tags: polymer

As far as I can tell from the documentation [here](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding.html#templates-with-data-binding) and [here](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#iterative-templates), the following should be right.  But it's not working.  I get no errors.  My page just says "test test" (You'll see why in the code).  What is wrong?

**NOTE** I had this working fine with core-ajax directly in a single blog entry, so I know my data is fine, etc

**slog-entry.html**  *this is the element for each entry in my demo blog app*

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link href="../core-ajax/core-ajax.html" rel="import">

<polymer-element name="slog-entry" noscript>
    <template>
        <h1>{{entry.Title}}</h1>
        <p>{{entry.Text}}</p>
        <span>{{entry.timestamp}}</span>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

**slog-entries.html** *this is the element for the collection of entries in my blog app*

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link href="../slog-entry/slog-entry.html" rel="import">
<polymer-element name="slog-entries" noscript>
    <template>
        <core-ajax auto
                   url="https://<server>/entries.json"
                   response="{{entries}}">
        </core-ajax>
        test
        <template repeat="{{entry in entries}}">
            <slog-entry bind="{{entry}}"></slog-entry>
        </template>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

**slog.html** *this is the index*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Status Log 0.1b</title>
    <script src="templates/platform/platform.js"></script>
    <link href="templates/slog-entries/slog-entries.html" rel="import">
    <link href="templates/polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>
test
    <slog-entries></slog-entries>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE** Here is what the DOM looks like:

[image]

Comment: Did you try importing core-ajax inside of slog-entries.html? core-ajax is not actually used in slog-entry.html, but you're importing it there.

Comment: Crap, I missed that when I converted it from a single entry to add the entries list.  I bet that's it...

Comment: That didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Actually, the individual entries rendering in the DOM now, they are just empty.  Must be something with the bind statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax `bind="{{entry}}"` doesn't do what I suspect you want it to do.

Polymer binding uses a syntax like this `<name of thing to bind to>="{{<source value>}}"`.

Now, in order to have a `name of thing to bind to`, elements must *publish* those names.

So, `slog-entry` has to look like this:

```
<polymer-element name="slog-entry" attributes="entry" noscript>
```

The `attributes="entry"` bit on the element causes `slog-entry` to accept bindings to property `entry` (this is what we call *publishing*).

Now your repeat can look like this:

```
    <template repeat="{{entry in entries}}">
        <slog-entry entry="{{entry}}"></slog-entry>
    </template>
```

We are telling the system to bind the `entry` property of each `slog-entry` to the `entry` value at each repeat.

Comment: That did it!  And it makes sense, which is a major bonus! :)